# Hackerrank small triangles, large triangles problem

Tags: c, struct, enums, structure

[Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/small-triangles-large-triangles/)
here is link to question. In this question we have to sort the triangles based on their areas and then print out the dimensions of triangle in sorted format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    /**
    * Sort an array a of the length n
    */
    double arr[n+1];
    
    triangle temp;
 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        double area_2,p;
        p=((tr[i].a+tr[i].b+tr[i].c)/2.0);
        area_2=(p*(p-tr[i].a)*(p-tr[i].b)*(p-tr[i].c));
        arr[i]=area_2;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
               temp=tr[i];
                tr[i]=tr[j];
                tr[j]=temp;
            }
            
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. Only sample testcase is getting passed with this code and all else testcases are wrong. can someone pls help me with this?

Comment: Please only tag the language you're actually program in. At least one of the features you use in your code is invalid in C++, so I assume you're programming in C?

Comment: As for your problem, unless you're tasked with writing the sorting algorithm itself, then use the standard [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function. And for the whole program the flow could be something like this: Do input, calculate the area, (could be done in the same loop where you get the input), sort, and do the output.

Comment: You can do structure assignments instead of member-wise assignments when swapping two structures in your sort code (3 lines instead of 9) —— `temp = tr[i]; tr[i] = tr[j]; tr[j] = temp;`  However, you also need to swap the `arr` entries when you swap the triangles — otherwise your areas are no longer matched with the triangles.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks but i dont think the error is in sorting.

Comment: The error is in the sorting code.  Or, at least, one of the errors is in the sorting code.  There may be others.  You currently have two arrays which have to be sorted simultaneously.  The standard library `qsort()` can't do that — you'd have to use some non-trivial subterfuges to make that work.

Comment: If you add the area to the `triangle` structure itself, or calculate it during sorting (on demand), then you only have one single array to sort which simplifies things. Then you can use `qsort` instead of your own bubble sort.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks guys but i already got the solution for this. actually the area array i was not sorting thats why the error was there.

Comment: Please consider deleting the question, or adding your working code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys for your help. finally with lots of debugging, i understood the error in my code. while swapping the structure array i was forgetting to swap the area array as well.Here is the code for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
#define longlong int;
void swap(double *array,int i,int j)
{
    int temp=array[i];
    array[i]=array[j];
    array[j]=temp;    
}
void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {

    double arr[n];

    triangle temp;
 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        double area_2,p;
        p=((tr[i].a+tr[i].b+tr[i].c)/2.0);
        area_2=(p*(p-tr[i].a)*(p-tr[i].b)*(p-tr[i].c));
        arr[i]=area_2;
/*storing square of area in a different array of different types of triangle*/
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
/*using bubble sort comparing the area of subsequent triangles and if area of subsequent triangles are found to be greater than the previous one then swapping the areas as well as the structure array*/
            {   swap(arr,i,j);
                temp=tr[i];
                tr[i]=tr[j];
                tr[j]=temp;
            }
            
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```